# How to get rid of Label name in visualforce page

Tags: apex

I have created one visual force page, in that page i am using one field in outputpanel, This field also showing field label name i dont know why. Please find my code for that field and screenshot for that field.

Any idea how can i get rid of that label name?

```
      <apex:outputPanel id="request">
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!t1.EventType__c=='EKH Week Event'}">


 <div class="form-group">

    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="evenytype">Need Volunteers?  <font color="red"></font> </label>                 
         <apex:inputField value="{!t1.EKH_Primary_Contact__c}" id="try"> 
                    </apex:inputField>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>   


           </apex:pageBlockSection>
           </apex:outputPanel>
```

[image: I mark the label name which showing automatically]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `label` property:

```
<apex:inputField label="No Longer Default" value="{!myFieldBinding}" />
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm):

> **label**
>
> A text value that allows you to override the default label that is displayed for the field. You can set label to an empty string to hide the label on forms. Setting it to null is an error.

Comment: I've removed my answer! Seeing as it's exactly the same as yours, plus, you beat me to it. ;)

Comment: @Poet Daww I was gonna up-vote anyway. It's such a race sometimes heh.